# CQL query to fetch data from multiple search criteran value

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

with big hope asking this question.geeks please suggest..
I have huge data stored into cassandra, with all US cities, state,lat and long. what would be the cql query to get lat and long of multiple city in multiple state.

## sample req

```
{
            "city": "Northbrook",
            "state": "IL"
        },
        {
            "city": "Chicago",
            "state": "IL"
        },
        {
            "city": "Schaumburg",
            "state": "IL"
        },
        {
            "city": "Omaha",
            "state": "NE"
        },
        {
            "city": "Bellevue",
            "state": "NE"
        },
        {
            "city": "Paige",
            "state": "AZ"
        }
```

Query used : select * from tablename where city in ('Northbrook','Paige','Chicago','Bellevue','Omaha','Schaumburg') and state in ('IL','AZ','NE')

problem is, it's not returning all six cities lat and long and other details. Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: the AND clause is saying that is has to be in both  is that what you need? also what is "tablename"?

Comment: Thanks for replying. tablename is my tablename like xyz.

Comment: Northbrook','Paige','Chicago - they belongs to state IL

Comment: Bellevue','Omaha - belongs to NE and Paige belongs to state AZ. in the cassandra table, they are present wilth lat and long. But when i use this query, it's not returning all rows. is there any way to make that query correct and efficient?

Comment: Do you only want those cities if so just use the `where city in ('Northbrook','Paige','Chicago','Bellevue','Omaha','Schaumburg')` part. I am not familiar with cassandra but it should be like SQL

Comment: What is your query returning now?

Comment: Thanks, for attening my question. Anyway I solved my problem, by adding partition key columns to support two operators,  "=" and "IN".Currently my query returning correct record. btw query is "select * from table name where city IN (...) AND state in (....);